# Navigation settings not applied after save

Tags: 2010, navigation, publishing-site, quick-launch

My site is a publishing site, therefor I get the navigation setting on site settings. Update: I made an empty site, and then I activated the features for a publishing site. When I use the publishing template, it worked fine.

But when I change order (I have everything manually sorted) it does not get applied when I save the settings.

The same if I delete the Library / Lists / Discussions from the quick launch and hit save, it will come back once I go back to navigation settings.

(The other settings on the navigation settings is saved).

But when I go to the hidden /_layouts/quiklnch.aspx settings, and delete the items from there, it gets applied. (but it doesn't show the pages).

Why does the navigation not work properly when I make a site from empty and activate publishing features, and works fine if I use the publishing template? Is it some configuration I need to do for it to work properly ?

Update: Everything I do in that controller where I can move up, down, delete, add links, show, hide etc does not get saved (or gets saved and reset).

Answer (score 2):

you may want to take a look at this [Change Left hand navigation sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint102.wordpress.com/2011/10/20/change-the-left-hand-navigation-sharepoint-2010/) and this [MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f901aa42-97ae-42d9-95e3-0881593a3b35/navigation-settings-not-saving?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

Helped us a lot.

**EDIT:**
we are currently tied up right now, but compelled to leave the answer just in case someone stumbles upon this. I was hoping to post an update later (off-work) but guess I have to leave work to answer this now, before this gets removed.

we had the same issue, and struggled to find out why or how the links doesn't save. turned out (we think) it is because the page we used had some default navigation settings, which we didn't bother to update, because they were defaults. then it came to us that we need to update the navigation.

as per post:

> But the solution to the Global Navigation not saving problem was that the  element by default is empty. I changed the empty NavBars element in onet.xml to

```
<NavBars>
  <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;" Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;" ID="1002" />
 </NavBars>
```

and we also updated the {0} in

```
<SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
<SharePoint:DelegateControl>
<Template_Controls>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider={0} />
</Template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
</SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>
```

to use the correct siteMapProvider.
*do not force me to post the codes here, it is policy.*

I hope this keeps downvotes away.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE updated for reference.